# Emission of photon in space

Tags: photon-emission

A source is emitting photons towards all directions. An observer sitting at millions of light years away can receive the photon from all the places. There will be infinite directions from where the photons can be observed. Is it possible if the source is emitting photons towards infinite (not huge) directions?

Comment: see [Olbers Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox) or do you mean [gravitational lenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens)?

Comment: I don't understand this question, although I see a relation to the proposed duplicate. Is *what* possible? What exactly are you confused about here?

Comment: Photons aren't being emitted in any one specific direction, at all. They are not small little balls that follow a straight trajectory. Other than that one can still count the photon flux. The sun emits approx. 4e26W in radiation. At the wavelength of green photons that's a photon flux of approx. 4e45 photons/s into an area of $4\pi R^2$. The photon flux in a distance of R is therefor on the order of $3.2e44/(R/m)^2s$. As you can see, there is still approx. 1 photon per $m^2s$ at a distance of approx. 1.8e22m. That's 1.9 million light years, roughly the distance to Andromeda.

Comment: I am sorry for my poor English. Thanks Mr. CuriousOne who has understood my question. Now We are sitting at 1.9 million light years away from the sun. We are getting one photon in an area of one sq meter (10000 sq. cms). The visibility of the photon is available at everywhere within the square meter area. Our eye has a limited area (say 1 sq. cms.) to view. It means that we are visualizing a fraction of photon at a time. Am I right?